# Ограничение уникальности не действующее на записи с определённым значением колонки

Tags: sql, oracle

Как я могу задать ограничение на несколько колонок, но при этом исключать определённые не `NULL` записи?

```
ALTER TABLE emp 
  ADD CONSTRAINT no_duplicates 
  UNIQUE ( dept, theme, date );
```

Но есть еще колонка `deleted` со значениями `0,1`. Нужно чтобы ограничение не действовало на записи, где колонка `deleted = 0`.

Comment: Ваша последняя правка не совсем понятна. Вы заменили "поле" на "запись".  Что теперь в новой редакции значит:  _констрейнт на несколько исключая некоторые записи_?

Comment: Спасибо, изменил

Comment: Термины "запись" и "строка" синонимы, т.е. пока ничего не изменилось. Может вы имели ввиду: "колонка" или "столбец"?

Comment: Попробовал сформулировать вашу задачу. Посмотрите, так соответствует тому, что вы хотели спросить?

Comment: Ограничение уникальности исключая определенные строки, тоже самое, какая разница между строка и запись, record and raw

Comment: Как и написал выше "запись" и "строка" синонимы, но "строка" часто ассоциируется со строчным значением одной колонки, поэтому, думаю - "запись" лучше подходит. В англ. _row_ более однозначно в этом контексте.

Comment: Хорошо, думаю ваш вариант более детально описывает вопрос, спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуемся тем фактом, что индексы в Oracle не хранят значения если весь ключ NULL и с ключом NULL может быть сколько угодно значений. Создадим такой уникальный функциональный индекс который для deleted=0 даст сами значения для полей, а для 1 даст для всех NULL.

```
create unique index emp_uniq on emp(
  decode(deleted,0,dept,NULL),
  decode(deleted,0,theme,NULL),
  decode(deleted,0,date,NULL)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать поле deleted целочисленного типа. 
Тогда процедура "удаления" может выглядеть где-то так

```
UPDATE emp e
  SET e.deleted =
    (SELECT max(deleted) + 1
     FROM emp i
     WHERE i.dept  = e.dept
       AND i.theme = e.theme
       AND i.date  = e.date)
WHERE e.empid = in_empid;
```

И можно делать unique constraint по четырём полям

---

Если приложение ждёт от базы данных только 0 или 1 в поле deleted, можно это решить используя представление или запрос в хранимой процедуре, возвращающей данные.

```
SELECT 
  e.empid, e.empname, e.dept,
  e.theme, e.date,
  case e.deleted when 0 then 0 else 1 end deleted
  FROM emp e;
```

Comment: К сожалению в этом поле может быть только два значения, 0 или 1.

Comment: @JNat почему только два?

Comment: так было задано архитектурой, и приложения уже работают с расчетом на два значения

Comment: @JNat программе можно подсунуть представление, где будут только 0 и 1.

Comment: да, это тоже хорошая идея, но в компании не используются хранимые процедуры, либо это просто сделать на бэкенде либо констрэйнтом, в коде буду просто делать запрос и смотреть есть ли такое же значение.

Comment: @JNat но представление-то можно использовать?

Comment: Можно попробовать, спасибо